# Disable Push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-уведомления

У меня есть клас  View Controller где пользователь решает включать ли уведомления в приложении.Когда он включает, ему каждый день приходят пуши. В другом. View controller я добавил switch который отвичает за вкл и выкл пушей. Но почему то при любом состоянии пуши всеровно приходят. ПОдскажите в чем проблема.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func  userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound])
    {
        (granted,error ) in
        print("granted\(granted)")
    }
    return true
}
```

**RegisterPush.swift**

```
func setupNotification()
{
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSLocalizedString("text",
            comment: "content.Title.Push")
    content.body =
            NSLocalizedString("text",
                    comment: "content.Body.Push")
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let date = Date()
    var triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
    triggerDate.hour = 9
    triggerDate.minute = 0
    triggerDate.second = 0

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "requestId",
        content: content,
        trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil )

    defaults.set(true, forKey: notificationKey)
}
```

**Settings**

```
@IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    print(" switch IF ")
    if(sender.isOn) {
        print("on")
        notification.setupNotification()
        defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "notification")

    }  else {
        print("Off") // Тут почему то не отключаютяс пуши
        UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
        defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "notification")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()` используйте `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()`